# how to read google doc and change content

Tags: google-docs-api

I'm wondering how to read a google docs content for changing the content fro:m a MySql request result?

Any help would be appreciated

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

I am using the document list API:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

to read google docs files.